# Force stop ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, devops

Is it possible to stop an ansible playbook?

I am not talking about failed_when condition or some other ansible modules, but actually killing the process!

Comment: You need to get ansible pid for this. I've tried with /proc/self/status and PPid (lookup plugin), but call chain is too long. If you can get ansible pid, just do `command kill -9 {{that_pid}}`.

Comment: `CTRL-C` is your friend

Answer (score 2):

From within the playbook, you could use:

- `assert` or `fail` to fail a task on a specific condition
- `all_errors_fatal` to force the entire playbook to stop when a task fails

From the outside world (Linux shell), you could use `CTRL-C` while the playbook is running on your terminal.

Or, from another terminal, you could get the PID of the ansible-playbook command (`ps aux | grep ansible-playbook`, for example), and `kill` that PID.